# Read and show all the data of a serialized file

Tags: java, object, serialization, file-io

I've been trying to show all the data that there are in serialized file, but I don't know how to do it. I only have could show the last data. How do I show all the data before the last?

This is the method I've been using:

```
public void lecturaRegistro() throws ClassNotFoundException {

    try {
        while (true) {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            Usuario usu = (Usuario) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Login: " + usu.getLogin());
            System.out.println("Clave: " + usu.getClave());
            System.out.println("Tipo: " + usu.getTipoU());

            ois.close();
            break;
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Usuario just contain single entity.fir you have to store a collection in serialized file and then while de-serialized you have to iterate over Collection.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        while (true) {

            Usuario usu = (Usuario) ois.readObject();
            if (usu == null) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Login: " + usu.getLogin());
                System.out.println("Clave: " + usu.getClave());
                System.out.println("Tipo: " + usu.getTipoU());
            }

        }
        ois.close();
```

You were reading only one object.. You need to read the entire file to display all objects